# How do we call a function with argument inside the main function

Tags: javascript

```
function getdata(){
   var data = new Array(700).fill('hey');
   console.log('c');
   return function(index)
   {
   return data[index]};
}
```

//i am trying to access the array of index value 8

getdata(8) ---> I am not getting the expected result

expected result :
hey

Comment: will you elaborate ?

Comment: `function getdata(index){return data[index];}`?

Comment: getdata returns a function, so you should use it like so `getdata()(8)`

Comment: const getIndex = getdata(); getIndex(8); this is working fine,  please someone explain me the logic.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sorry but I have not enough reputation to comment, so solution is to run it as:

```
getdata()(8)
```

Comment: Don't be sorry. This is a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `getdata` return a function you need to call that again.

```js
function getdata(){
   var data = new Array(700).fill('hey');
   console.log('c');
   return function(index)
   {
      return data[index]
   };
}
console.log(getdata()(8))
```

Or if you don't want to use `()()` syntax just return call the inner function inside `getdata`

```js
function getdata(){
   var data = new Array(700).fill('hey');
   console.log('c');
   return function(index)
   {
      return data[index]
   }(...arguments);
   
}
console.log(getdata(8))
```